# Gdata youtube api for objective-c - getting videos playable in iPhone

Tags: iphone, youtube-api, gdata-api

I am using the gdata library in my iPhone app to search for some youtube videos. Now most of the videos come up fine but some videos are not compatible for playback with the iPhone. I am using a webview to embed the video.

In case of videos which cannot be played on the iPhone, they show up in the webview without a preview and just a play button with a cross.

I could not find anything in the YouTube API which would let me get only those video results that are playable on the iPhone. Anyone know of a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifying iPhone-playable YouTube videos has been discussed in the GData mailing lists, such as [here](http://groups.google.com/group/gdata-objectivec-client/browse_thread/thread/53d83c793bbe3368/6a28926d57dcd8ad)